# Rails: join with multiple conditions

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, join

I have a simple model like

```
class Interest < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :user_profiles
end

class UserProfile < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :interests
end
```

When I want to query all the users with a specific interests, that's fairly simple doing

```
UserProfile.joins(:interests).where('interests.id = ?', an_interest)
```

But how can I look for users who have multiple interests? Of course if I do

```
UserProfile.joins(:interests).where('interests.id = ?', an_interest).where('interests.id = ?', another_interest)
```

I get always an empty result, since after the join, no row can have simultaneously interest.id = an_interest and interest.id = another_interest.

Is there a way in ActiveRecord to express "I want the list of users who have 2 (specified) interests  associated?

**update (solution)** that's the first working version I came up, kudos to Omar Qureshi

```
    specified_interests.each_with_index do |i, idx|
      main_join_clause = "interests_#{idx}.user_profile_id = user_profiles.id"
      join_clause = sanitize_sql_array ["inner join interests_user_profiles interests_#{idx} on
                    (#{main_join_clause} and interests_#{idx}.interest_id = ?)", i]

      relation = relation.joins(join_clause)
    end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in (?) is no good - it's an OR like expression

what you will need to do is have multiple joins written out longhanded

```
profiles = UserProfile
interest_ids.each_with_index do |i, idx|
  main_join_clause = "interests_#{idx}.user_profile_id = user_profiles.id"
  join_clause = sanitize_sql_array ["inner join interests interests_#{idx} on
                        (#{main_join_clause} and interests_#{idx}.id = ?)", i]
  profiles = profiles.join(join_clause)
end
profiles
```

You may need to change the main_join_clause to suit your needs.

Comment: That's way more complicated that I hoped :) ! But you definitely pointed me to the right direction. Thanks. The only difference is I had to `inner join interests_user_profiles` rather than `inner join interests` as you wrote.

Comment: ...and also replace `interests_#{idx}.id = ?` with `interests_#{idx}.interest_id = ?`

Comment: ah right - it was a M-to-M join? that would make sense, sorry didn't read that bit! :D

Answer (score 2):

This will get users that have at least one of the specified interests.

```
UserProfile.joins(:interests).where(:id => [an_interest_id, another_interest_id])
```

To get users that have both of the specified interests I'd probably do something like this:

```
def self.all_with_interests(interest_1, interest_2)
  users_1 = UserProfile.where("interests.id = ?", interest_1.id)
  users_2 = UserProfile.where("interests.id = ?", interest_2.id)

  users_1 & users_2
end
```

Not amazingly efficient, but it should do what you need?

Comment: I tried   `UserProfile.joins(:interests).where("interests.id = ?" , [25, 26])`  but it didn't work

Comment: No, it still doesn't work. I get a syntax error in the query `SELECT "user_profiles".* FROM "user_profiles" INNER JOIN "interests_user_profiles" ON "interests_user_profiles"."user_profile_id" = "user_profiles"."id" INNER JOIN "interests" ON "interests"."id" = "interests_user_profiles"."interest_id" WHERE (interests.id = 25,26)`

Comment: I have just read your comment on another answer - I didn't realise you needed a logical AND. My answer will do an OR.

Answer (score -1):

Try `IN (?)` and an array:

```
UserProfile.joins(:interests).where('interests.id IN (?)', [1,2,3,4,5])
```

Comment: the IN clause makes a logical OR (has one interest or the other or both)... I need a logical AND (has all the interests)