# find in a "anded" array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have 2 tables : `entradas (id, blah...)` and `georelaciones (:entrada_id, lugar_id, blah...)`. `georelaciones` is just a link table for a polymorphic relation.

I want to retrieve all the `entradas` which are in relation with each `lugar_id` (pass in an array).

I have build this ugly `scope` ("d" will be an array of `lugar_id`):

```
scope :con_pais, lambda {|d|
  # select e.id from entradas as e inner join georelaciones as g1 on (g1.lugar_id = 55 and g1.entrada_id = e.id) inner join georelaciones as g2 on (g2.lugar_id = 66 and g2.entrada_id = e.id)
  cadena = ""
  i = 0 
  d.each{ |lugar_id| i += 1 ; cadena << " inner join georelaciones as g" + i.to_s + " on (g"+ i.to_s + ".lugar_id = " + lugar_id.to_s + " and g" + i.to_s + ".entrada_id = e.id)"}
  entradas = Entrada.find_by_sql("select distinct e.id from entradas as e " + cadena)
  a = []
  entradas.each{ |e| a << e.id }
  Entrada.where("id in (?)", a)
  }
```

I know that's not good because my table `entradas` has some million records and I do not take advantage of lazy loading due to the use of `find_by_sql`.

How can I query the database and return an `ActiveRecord::Relation` directly without using `find_by_sql`?

Comment: Can't really understand what you are doing here, firstly - that query doesn't look like its SQLi safe. But, it looks similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5376869/rails-join-with-multiple-conditions/5377304#5377304

Comment: ;( it's return an array! I want an ActiveRecord::Relation. The query above that i buid return an ActiveRecord::Relation but i have todo some eager_loading before (find_by_sql)

Comment: Read that question linked above - it takes an array and returns a joined AR Relation.

Comment: ok i did it (sorry for the late answer!):  <code>    scope :con_pais_omar, lambda {|d|
      entradas = Entrada
      d.each_with_index do |i, idx|
        main_join_clause = "georelaciones_{idx}.entrada_id = entrada.id"
        join_clause = sanitize_sql_array ["inner join georelaciones_{idx} on
       (#{main_join_clause} and georelaciones_{idx}.id = ?)", i]
        entradas = entradas.joins(join_clause)
      end 
    } </code>  but it is slower and take more resource as mine... thanks any way

Answer (score 0):

```
Entrada.find_by_sql("select distinct e.id from entradas as e " + cadena)
```

=>

```
Entrada.select("distinct e.id as e #{cadena}")
```

Comment: i don't think we can use select in this way!

Comment: @pascal, ha :) you don't think, or you know it :). Of course you can. Just try it

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that I got your relations correct, you should be able to do something like this:

```
class Georelacion < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :entrada

  scope :con_pais, lambda { |d|
    includes(:entrada).where("georelaciones.lugar_id IN (?)", d)
  }

  ...
end
```

And then in the controller:

```
@lugar_ids = [1,2,3,4]
@georelaciones = Georelacion.con_pais(@lugar_ids).group_by(&:lugar_id)
```

That should give you a hash where each key is a lugar_id and the value for each key is an array of georelaciones with the associated entrada already loaded from the database.

Comment: between each term of the "in" it 's an "or" not a "and" as it say in khttp://stackoverflow.com/questions/5376869/rails-join-with-multiple-conditions/5377304#5377304 as say omar,thank any way